# phpredis scan method laravel

Tags: laravel, redis, redis-cluster, phpredis

Running my application inside a redis cluster and I stumbled about a strange issue:

```
dd(Redis::connection('default')->scan('0', [
    'match' => 'my_application_cache_*',
    'count' => 999,
]));
```

returns:

```
array:2 [▼ // app/Http/Controllers/User/ProfileController.php:30
  0 => 1
  1 => []
]
```

Running the same command with `redis-cli` like:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 0 MATCH my_application_cache_* COUNT 9999
```

returns:

```
1) "0"
2)  1) "my_application_cache_:SLY6WWj9cymyZzJk0BihOYAm7uNQT9T55bYrvGMB"
    2) "my_application_cache_:IDF8Qe713Y06XOEmaQC7mzyupKgURusIaTxLt1Nx"
    3) "my_application_cache_:4JRZ1Zd8hg2FwQzO5JTRlWuyxIi07V0ERqXtAVer"
    4) "my_application_cache_:GWv8tisv4xQAgBaXdJap62aJh95V5mWvTiw9CQ0X"
    5) "my_application_cache_:hTKTDsUN9YsuuHlxJdFSflL737MvvPZPX0O9uNLQ"
```

Any idea why laravel isn't returning any values inside the `1` element of the array?

Comment: Have you done a subsequent scan using `1` as the cursor? That's what redis is telling you to do I think. Check the docs for `scan` maybe your issue has to do with the fact that it filters out entries that don't match your glob after fetching results, so you can end up with empty result sets for a given cursor. Just a guess though